# Non-Linear Distributed Delayed Kalman Filter

Tags: optimization, linear-system, probability, optimal-control

I have a system $\vec{x}_{i + 1} = \vec{x}_i + W_i$ where $W = N(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma)$. For some matrix $H_i$, let $y_i = H_i$ and let $z_i = y_i + R$. Where $R$ is some random variable. We are given $pdf(y_i | z_i)$. Using this, I can calculate the mean and the covariance of $y_i$ conditioned on the observation $z_i$ (I am using numerical integration or Monte Carlo methods). But due to computational performance reasons, the calculated value of the mean and the covariance is not available until time $i + d$.

The Question: What is a good heuristics to update the mean and the covariance of $x_i$?

I attempted to linearize the system by heuristically constructing a fake observation $z'_i$ and $R'_i = N(0, \Sigma_{R'})$ such that mean and covariance of $y_i$ conditioned on $z'_i$ matched the expected value and the covariance calculated in the non-linear system. And then I apply the fake observation using standard Kalman Filter logic. Unfortunately, I have noticed that there is "double counting" due to the delay. When $x_i$ moves significantly $E[y_i|z_i]$ is significantly different from $E[y_i]$. To account for this, my fake observation $z_i$ needs to be large. But since this observation is not accounted for until time $i + d$, at time $i+1$, I will have another extreme value of $z_{i + 1}$. This causes me to over shoot.

I have not used the standard particle filter, because my system is very high in dimension, and the variance of the particle filter estimator is way too high.

Is there a different approach I can try?